# powershell Empty value override by other value excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have this problem where i have 2 files and the output are:

value from file A is "No data"

value from file B is "prior to versions 0.9.8zd"

when I tried to write it on excel cell using powershell, value B always override value A. How to prevent this?

```
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$dir="c:\users\john\desktop\"
$msgs=get-childitem $dir -filter "*.msg"
$rgx="blabla"    
$regex="blablabla"

$xl=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.visible=$true
$wkbk=$xl.workbooks.add()
$wkbk.worksheets.add()
$wksht=$workbook.worksheets.item(1)

$wksht.name="TEST"
$wksht.cells.item(1,11)="Version(s)"

foreach($msg in $msgs)
{
$msg=$outlook.CreateitemFromTemplate($dir+$msg)
$body=$msg.body

if($body -match $rgx)
{
#echo "true"
$version=$body|select-string -pattern $regex -allmatches |%{$_.matches}|%{$_.value}
}

$row=$wksht.usedrange.rows.count+1

$usedrange=$wksht.usedrange
$usedrange.entirecolumn.autofit()|out-null

 if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($version))
 {
 $wksht.cells.item($row,11)="No data"
 }
 else
 {
 $wksht.cells.item($row,11)=$version
 }
```

Expected result :

No Data                   <----first row,
prior to versions 0.9.8zd <-------2nd row

But what I got :

prior to versions 0.9.8zd  <----first row,
prior to versions 0.9.8zd <-------2nd row

Your help highly appreciated. That's basically the whole code. do I missing something

Comment: What's with the dot after the closing paren `$worksheet.cells.item($row,11)>.<="No data"`?  Is that a typo because it doesn't look like valid PowerShell syntax.

Comment: sorry..it's a typo.edited it

Comment: How are you looping through the rows?

Comment: I'm using for..loop for each file

Comment: The code that you are showing is insufficient to replicate the issue. Please provide additional code, as what you have here most likely isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what the input data is, you say `value from file A is "No data"`, but in your script you are testing for `IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: I use regex to look for the string from the file. if it find the pattern, the output will be the pattern but if it can't be found, the output is 'No data'